# jquery and updatepanel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an updatepanel in ASP.NET that does a partial page refresh.

I've had some success using jQuery's `on()` method, however `$(document).ready(function(){})` is only called during the initial load of a page, rather than after each updatepanel refresh.

I think I could probably trigger it using '`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`' but would prefer a 'cleaner' method. Do any exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use [pageLoad](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)() function in JS

```
function pageLoad()
{
 // put your code when returning from update panel request.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register an `endRequest` handler using a line similar to this (in your Javascript):

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(){})
```

This will execute after each of your updates.