# How to show notification or message from server-Side in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As you can see *`I want to show to client some text which are most Important for Client's`*. so I plan to show Alert form server side . for implementing this I create **JScript Function** Like below Code:

```
 function ShowMessage(s) {
        alert(s);
 }
```

So in cs code write this method to call **JS-Function**:

```
public static void ShowMessage(System.Web.UI.Page Pointer, string Message)
{
    if (!Pointer.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("message"))
        Pointer.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
            (Pointer.Master.GetType(), "message", "ShowMessage('" + Message + "');", true);
}
```

**`This Code work well ;)`**

So I try to approve My web-app. and **`using Update-panel and Script-Manager`**. after using them I Got new Problem.(put all button in Update-Panel)

In each *`Button-Click`* or better say for each *`Post-back`* occur, If Call `ShowMessage` method -> **Nothing happen**. no message , no alert!!!

Question :

- Why this code don't work in Update-Panel?
- How to Fix this? or Is It better way to show message?

Comment: I think the solution to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263793/jquery-and-updatepanel) will also solve your case.

Comment: When using update panel only a part of the web page is rendered. I don't think any scripts registered with `Page.ClientScript` are rendered at all (only when doing a "real" postback)

Comment: I think you used nearly all the possible formatting options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void ShowMessage(System.Web.UI.Page Pointer, string Message)
{
    if (!Pointer.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("message"))
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Pointer,
                                          Pointer.Master.GetType(),
                                          "message", 
                                          "ShowMessage('" + Message + "');", 
                                          true);
}
```

Since you are using update panels therefore that functionality didn't work which you were using previously without update panels because the page life cycle of your webpage changed after using that update panel control, `Page.ClientScript` woks only with traditional web page life cycle.

For more you may like to go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, It work. Also can You describe more info about your solution!